# cordova plugin not addable | Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

For a few days now, I am trying to add a plugin myself based on the documentation on the cordova homepage and I am beginning to doubt myself... It cant be that hard... https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html
I started with the German version (because I am from Germany) and was disappointed. It is written terribly. Just the quality of the text itself is bad. I didn't go far enough to evaluate the content.
I switched to the English version which is good, and I think I followed every step and have everything set up as it should be, but when I try to run my project (or a blank project for that matter) with the plugin added, I get the following error:

```
07-24 03:51:15.036 29983-29983/? D/CordovaWebViewImpl: 
onPageDidNavigate(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-24 03:51:15.247 29983-29983/io.cordova.hellocordova D/JsMessageQueue: Set 
native->JS mode to EvalBridgeMode
07-24 03:51:15.286 29983-29983/io.cordova.hellocordova 
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-
echo-js/www/echo.js: Line 28 : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a 
function
07-24 03:51:15.286 29983-29983/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium: 
[INFO:CONSOLE(28)] "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", 
source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-echo-js/www/echo.js 
(28)
07-24 03:51:15.290 29983-29983/io.cordova.hellocordova D/CordovaWebViewImpl: 
onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-24 03:51:15.384 29983-29983/io.cordova.hellocordova 
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 36 : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
07-24 03:51:15.384 29983-29983/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium: 
[INFO:CONSOLE(36)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' 
of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (36)
```

This is the environment that I have set up:

```
Windows 8 64 bit Enterprise 
Android Studio 2.3.3 
$ cordova -v 7.0.1 
$ npm --version 3.10.10 
$ git --version git version 2.13.2.windows.1 
$ grunt --version grunt-cli v1.2.0 
$ bower --version 1.8.0
```

I googled a bit of course and tried various "solutions". Removing the plugins, removing the platforms adding them back up. Starting a project from scratch. Adding the plugins in different ways and other stuff that I am missing now for sure. None of the solutions helped me.

I appreciate any kind of help. This problem is really annoying me. 
Regards

Dawid

EDIT (27.07.2017): Added index.js echo.js in the comments as gist

Comment: Can you share your index.js and echo.js? The error seems to be in the code in these 2 files.

Comment: echo.js: https://gist.github.com/Fakerinc/7fc1a8cb852c2079cf3695b8191b7abd index.js: https://gist.github.com/Fakerinc/74966f62803a096325e3ee8434632c60

Answer (score 0):

The erros are not due to anything related to cordova.

The first error "echo-js/www/echo.js: Line 28 : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a 
function" occurs because in your echo.js, the line 28 i.e. windows.echo is undefined. The context of window.echo is lost as it is being used inside the function.

The second error is in index.js : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null". The js is unable to find the element defined by 'id' and consequently the variable "parentElement" is null which causes this error.

If you could share the complete project, resolving these errors would be easier.

Comment: thank you for your comment @Keerthi I see what you mean. Because it is inside the cordova.define(){} function? the interesting thing is/was that this definition code was auto generated for me if I recall correctly. Why would cordova generate faulty code? Sharing the whole project? Upload it completly on to git with the complete structure?

Comment: Yes. You can upload it to git and share as long as there is no sensitive or private data.

Comment: there shouldn't be any private/sensitive data in this dummy project https://github.com/Fakerinc/cordova-test

Comment: I figured it out. The error had to do with cordova. I didn't call the stuff in the device ready function/didn't wait for the device ready event to trigger. For everybody else that is having the same problem. The solution is: Read the documentation carefully even if it is not that great to read and understand.  Thank you for your help though @Keerthi